# Redirecting value in same page

Tags: php, html

lets say, I am sending a question number from page a.php to page b.php.

```
<a href=../home/Open.php?var=$row[id]></a>
```

After receiving the question number in b.php at

```
$var=$_GET['var'];
```

now the problem is I want to redirect the same page b.php using header

```
header("Location:open.php?var=".$var);
```

and passing the same value that I received from a.php.

Now is it possible to receive the value at

```
$var=$_GET['var'];
```

again?

Comment: @Rizier123  have tried but $var is empty when i am redirecting at same page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var` is empty because you use your PHP value wrong.

- There is no `quote` around `id` - if `id` is not a variable.
- No `echo`
- No `<?php ?>` around it.

Should be:

```
<a href="../home/Open.php?var=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: everything is inside <?php ?>, i have just posted the required lines for better explanation.
and first time when i am passing value from page a.php to b.php its working fine.

Comment: @SatyendraRoutela Can you show me how you write it inside `<?php ?>` ? There are different ways to write code, it would be useful if you show it so I won't assume.

Comment: trust me i have written it correctly inside <?php ?> :D

<?php
<a href=../home/Open.php?var=$row[id]></a>
?>
and i can clearly the value in url when it is passed to b.php